# Why Heroku requests times are slower / faster after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm using Heroku for a production Rails application.

I'm monitoring it with scoutapp and noticed that requests time can be 4 times slower or faster after a deploy in production.

I made some screenshots this time, but this happened multiple times, if I'm luky it will be fast after deploy.

**The deployment just contains a css update**

[image]

[image]
[image]

heroku stats also shows slower response time:

[image]

Comment: I reverted back to the version that was fast (in the screenshot) but it's slow, so this proves that the performance issue is not due to the deployment

Comment: did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Nope, I guess this is what you get when using a shared instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that slower times are due to cache being cleared when you deploy and the server restarts. When each request is cached again you would expect it to speed back up.
I can't offer an explanation for the faster times though.

Comment: This is not an answer please.

Comment: Yes cache could be an option but I use memcache to store it and avoid cache writing cost after deploy.